# how to communicate mobile app with the soap web service server with out ip address and port

Tags: android, web-services, delphi, soap, delphi-xe8

I am developing mobile apps by using Delphi XE8. And also I made soap webservice server by using Delphi XE8. I am developing internal mobile app for an organization. I install webservice server at the organization internal server. And the mobile app communicates with that webservice server. The webservice server publish the soap service. for example http://192.168.1.125:16645.

The mobile app has to be configured this URL to communicate with the server since this changes for every organization.

I don't want to give such a configuration to mobile app users. Could you help me out how can I automate this with this kind of URL?

Any domain things?

Comment: To be automatic there must be something within the app (or within app data - e.g. ini file) to tell the app which server to use. Otherwise it cannot be automated. This something might as well be the server IP/Port.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery

Comment: @TOndrej I don't think that is what the writer is wanting - otherwise app tethering would be appropriate. The problem with app tethering (and indeed discovery) is that unless you have a remote IP address somehow it only works locally.

Comment: @Dsm Why not? Dynamic WS-Discovery has been designed exactly for this purpose. The client can send a UDP multicast "Probe" or "Resolve" message and the service/proxy will send a unicast response announcing its endpoint.

Comment: @TOndrej. Yes, it was. And indeed app tethering uses this technique, I believe. But it is my understanding that this only works on computers on the same subnet, which is not my understanding of the requirement. I only dabble in UDP, though, and if I am wrong I will stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are server implementations such as ActiveMQ which broadcast their own server name via UDP, so that clients can locate them automatically.

See for a related question: [Discover a running ActiveMQ message broker using IP multicast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285666/discover-a-running-activemq-message-broker-using-ip-multicast) and a related blog post by me (with source code) [here](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/discover-activemq-brokers-with-delphi-and-ip-multicast/) and [here](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/discover-activemq-brokers-with-delphi-xe4-and-indy-10-6/). Indy can be used with the Delphi mobile compilers, so this code should work with your apps.

You can implement the same logic with your server, as long as there are no network restrictions for UDP.

Comment: Firstly, there are multiple servers (as I understand it). If you need the name of the server you may as well use its DNS address or IP address. Secondly the same UDP restrictions will apply to this as app tethering, so if this does work you may as well use app tethering which requires less in depth understanding and is easier to implement.

Comment: @Dsm as I understand `I don't want to give such a configuration to mobile app users`, the app has to be agnostic of the IP address / DNS name when it is run the first time. So UDP broadcast is a typical use case, similar to Rendezvous / Bonjour.

Comment: The line "The mobile app has to be configured this URL to communicate with the server since this changes for every organization." kind of negates that for me.